# Flash Builder 4.5 vs MySQL = )/&(%&{[](/&¤#%$£@

Tags: mysql, flash, builder

I'm stuck in Adobe Flash Builder 4.5.1. I'm trying to connect to a MySQL-database, running locally. When Flash Builder tries to connect with the build-in tool, the program returns this:

"“¹FÿÖ–4® ™‘ÔûOØÓ:¶›õÊ&A‰ô“‰@§Å�§­ç¢Ô�‚´ÖfÅêÅ™FgÖç."

I have MySQL, Zend and Apache2, all in it newest truest form. I have, as it requests "Amf.production = false". I have tried changing the characterset of the database. I have tried moving the database to a different computer. I have tried connecting to a different remote (www) database. All with same result.

What could be wrong?

Comment: How exactly do you connect to mysql? Also you can post some code.